# The Switch Statement and page content control

Tags: java, jpanel, switch-statement

I've been trying to create a class that decides which JPanel gets printed on a JFrame. The JPanels are "addNew" and "searchPanel". addNew is created by a class called "AddNew" and it contains content items that enables a user add new content into a database.
The searchPanel panel is in a different class "SearchPanel" that enables a user search content in a database.

The JFrame on which the two JPanels are drawn is in its own class and has only two buttons "Add new item" and "Search". No JPanel is drawn until one of these buttons is clicked.

Theres a third class that determines which JPanel gets drawn on the JFrame via a switch statement depending on a value (1 or 2) passed on "buttonClick", which is where I think I'm having problems.

My code so far:

```
import Panels.AddNew;
import SearchWakili.SearchPanel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Redirect {
    public static JPanel panelRedirect = new JPanel();

    public static JPanel value;

    public static JPanel pageAddNewFunction () {
        AddNew addNew = new AddNew();
        panelRedirect.add(addNew);
        return panelRedirect;
    }

    public static JPanel SearchPanelFunction () {
        SearchPanel searchPanel = new SearchPanel();
        panelRedirect.add(searchPanel);
        return panelRedirect;
    }

    public static JPanel pageRedirect (int pageID) {
        switch (pageID) {
            case 1:
                value = pageAddNewFunction();
            break;
            case 2:
                value = SearchPanelFunction();
                break;
        }
        return value;

    }

}
```

The code does nothing. I don't get any code error messages, though. The JPanels print fine when I call the directly without redirecting via the "Redirect" class.
What is it that I'm doing wrong, and is there any other way I can use an independent class to decide on a JPanel to be drawn depending on the button clicked?

Thank you very much in advance.

Oh! And I don't want to use CardLayout. I'd like to learn how to code this myself.

Part of the code that draws the JFrame:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FrameContainer {
    public static  JFrame Home;

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create and set up the Frame
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        Home = new JFrame();
        Home.setUndecorated(true);
        Home.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        Home.setResizable(false);
        Home.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
        Home.setBackground(Color.gray);

        // Redirect redirect = new Redirect();
        Home.add(Redirect.panelRedirect);

        // Display the window
        Home.pack();
        Home.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Part of the Code that declares the event:

```
public class Home {

    // The method that calls the type of JPanel (1) to be drawn
    private void mouseClickedAddNew(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        // FrameContainer.createAndShowGUI();
        Redirect.pageRedirect(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, it is not a good practice to initialize modules on request.

In other words, you should have a method that gets called in the main class constructor that will allocate space for the variables and do calculations, so when you actually click the button, the only command that you are running is the one that makes each panel visible.

This is most likely why what you are doing does not work.

So just make the code initially load both panels, then when a button is clicked, do show() or hide() (I believe those are the methods, but I don't use Swing often enough to know, so the wording may be different).